# VS Code on tab statements

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I want to change a default behavior of VS Code. As an example if i type `func` and then press `tab` it will generate `function` instead of the statement:

```
function name(params) {

}
```

[image]
Could you please advice me how to configure the editor correctly?

P.S. Sorry if its a duplicate of an already existed question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Pavel Griza Besides enabling tab completion with `"editor.tabCompletion": true`, also try setting `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"`. This ensures that the `function` statement snippet is listed before the `function` keyword item

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue with the settings:

```
{
    "editor.tabCompletion": true
}
```

`VSCode` still adds `function` after typing `func` and pressing `Tab` but if to press `Tab`key again if will add complete functional statement.